# Google Earth Engine: Export an entire collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to export all the images that the collection (code) contains. How can I do that?

```js
var colection = ee.ImageCollection ("MODIS/NTSG/MOD16A2/105")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want an automatized process you'll have to use the Python API. If you can do that, follow:

1. Install geetools (https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools)

> pip install geetools

2. Export Collection using a python script. As you want to export a MODIS collection, I highly recommend you use a region parameter.

```python
from geetools import batch
import ee
ee.Initialize()

col = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/NTSG/MOD16A2/105")
region = ee.Geometry.Polygon([XXXX])

help(batch.Export.ImageCollection.toDrive)  # See help for function

tasks = batch.Export.ImageCollection.toDrive(col, 'MyFolder', region=region, scale=1000)
```

Otherwise, if you don't mind clicking "Run" for every image, you can use geetools in the code editor (https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor), follow:

```js
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')
var col = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/NTSG/MOD16A2/105")
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon([XXXX])

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(col, 'MyFolder', 
      {region: region,
       scale: 1000})
```

Comment: it says "module 'geetools.batch' has no attribute 'ImageCollection'". Is anything change in the package?

Comment: yes, use `geetools.batch.Export.imagecollection.toDrive`