# Exporting entire ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine using geetools for JavaScript or Python for Windows?

Tags: export, google-earth-engine, landsat-8

I am very new to ee and am trying to export a collection to my drive, after masking for clouds and clipping to *myregion*... tried to follow the advice in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1 where the col2drive function is imported from geetools. But I seem not to have access to the repo, it doesn't show under my read module. Took me a while to find out because the error said is not a function, and thought I was not creating the object correctly.
So I copied the hardcoded version posted here [Export each image from a collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248216/export-each-image-from-a-collection-in-google-earth-engine) to my own repo and tried to load it from there, did not work. I get again and error saying col2drive is not a function... when I do  `var exportfunction = tools.col2drive;` and  `print(exportfuncion)`... it prints "undefined". So is not loading it, I think.

Then I found this other option [Google Earth Engine: Export an entire collection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276500/google-earth-engine-export-an-entire-collection), running it directly from python API. Installed python in my computer (Windows10, 64 bits), and when trying to install `geetools` it needs a module  `'fcntl'`, which apparently does not exist for Windows... there is a suggestion of using  `win32api`, but then again is for windows32 and the advice says that it is important to understand what  `fcntl` is doing in each case before substituing... In any case I have no idea where can I substitue it. 
Could someone help, I did try.

Here is my (stitched) code in case is useful

```js
var geometry = /* color: #98ff00 */geometry;

//Add tools to export collection
// load tools from Fito Principe
//var tools = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:tools');
var tools = require('users/sulazul/Rep:col2Drive')
// add col2drive function
var exportfunction = tools.col2Drive;
print(exportfunction)

// Load Landsat 8 imagery and filter it  
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                   .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 33))
                   .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 41))
                   .set('SENSOR_ID', 'OLI_TIRS')
                   .sort("CLOUD_COVER", false);
var count = collection.size()
print("Coleccion", count)

//some more code here to maskclouds and clip to myregion

// Map the function .
var filtered_1 = filtered.map(maskL8sr);
// export collection to google drive
exportfunction(filtered_1,"Landsat8", {
  scale: 30, 
  region: geometry.getInfo()["coordinates"], 
  type: 'float'
});
```

Comment: I'll have a look at python `geetools` for Windows

Comment: Question for Abhilash Singh Chauhan:
Can you explain what is agrimask_2001?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am the author of both `geetools` (Python and JavaScript)

The JavaScript repo is share with `anyone can read` so it should work, but anyhow you can click [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/fitoprincipe/geetools) to accept the repo, and then do:

```js
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

// Load Landsat 8 imagery and filter it  
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 33))
          .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 41))
          .set('SENSOR_ID', 'OLI_TIRS')
          .sort("CLOUD_COVER", false);
var count = collection.size()
print("Coleccion", count)

//some more code here to maskclouds and clip to myregion

// Map the function .
var filtered_1 = filtered.map(maskL8sr);
// export collection to google drive
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(filtered_1, 'Landsat8', {
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry.getInfo()["coordinates"] // or geometry.getInfo()
})
```

Documentation here: https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch#imagecollectiontodrivecollection-folder-options

Comment: Hola Rodrigo. I followed your advice and now I'm getting $name is not defined in this scope, what I'm doing is:                                                                                     // Map the function .
var filtered_1 = filtered.map(maskL8sr);

var listOfImages = filtered_1.toList(filtered_1.size());
var Image1 = listOfImages.get(0);
var Image2 = listOfImages.get(1);
var Test = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Image1, Image2]);
  
  print('Test',Test)
  
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(Test, 'Landsat8', 
 {name:'Test',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry
})

Comment: get a link and pass it to me (as a comment here)

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/98cb1e9305ac67eabb9188c79a8229fd

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your work and time! It is working now!... don't have enough points to vote, but really grateful.

Comment: It's fine! glad to help =)

Comment: how the python one works? what is the package for it?

Comment: https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools // pip install geetools

Comment: when I do
{
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(Grant_2018_IC_first, 'LLL', {
  scale: 10 // ,
  // region: geometry.getInfo()["coordinates"] // or geometry.getInfo()
})

}

I get the error

{
collection.size is not a function
}

Comment: better open an issue [here](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/issues) if you are using the JS API or [here](https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools/issues) if you are using the Python API

Comment: @oveflow-police & @rodrigo-e-principe, I believe `collection.size() is not a function` error is because `ee.List` of images is being provided, not `ee.ImageCollection` to the export function

Comment: She, can be that.. if the parameter `collection` is an `ImageCollection`, that error should not occur

Comment: Hey @RodrigoE.Principe, your answers were helpful but is there any way by which it automatically takes the name of Image/raster assigned to a variable, because I have to give a name every time to each raster in the task while uploading to google drive? and there is also confusion when list is large, it may lead to assigning wrong name manually.

Comment: Hi @AbhilashSinghChauhan, I changed the link to the documentation, if you see there you'll see that there is a `name` parameter that you can use to do what you want

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe, thanks for replying, But it is taking the same name for all the files. Can you please see it here at https://code.earthengine.google.com/fd3c14cce2cd537e0be434f9a0a567d1

Comment: Also I tried to follow your batch download from Github so that I dynamically changes the name of raster while uploading to GoogleDrive https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki/Batch#download , but it is also not working, not sure where I am making a mistake  https://code.earthengine.google.com/41a6afc69b53e35c03a0c75b1459a30b

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan the images you are trying to export do not have a `system:time_start` property that defines the image date, but it has a `system:index` property, you can use it like this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/1d071cdafffeb3e13f682ab9ae65aac3

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoE.Principe, it is working fine now, Anyway It worked with this way too, https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/45a6aae544eb3e593763b7db5e5b6e2e , thanks for your time.

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe How can I export each image using its `id` as name? Im trying this: `batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(s2_ext_features, 'folder', {name: '{id}', scale: 10, region: extent, type: 'float'});`

Answer (score 0):

In case of MODIS, you can download the batch of tiles as this

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')  
                .filterBounds(haryana)
                .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                .select('NDVI') 
                
var count = collection.size()

var all_tiles = collection.map(function(image) { return image.multiply(0.0001).clip(haryana).mask(agrimask_2001).reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 500); }); 
  

var collectionList = all_tiles.toList(all_tiles.size());
var n = collectionList.size().getInfo();

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var listOfImages = all_tiles.toList(all_tiles.size());
      var Tile = listOfImages.get(i);
      var allRasters = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Tile]);
      
      batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(allRasters, "MODIS Test Download", 
      {name: 'MODIS_{system:index}',
      scale: 500,
      region: yourAreaOfInterest
      })
}
```