# Unable to transform features into projection, Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, modis, ndvi

I have the following code with which I try to export the MODIS NDVI index.
I have rescaled the collection with the appropriate scale factor and code runs without errors. 
When I try though to download one of the available images, I get **"Error: Projection error: Unable to transform 
features into projection "**.

Does this error means that I must project my collection?

Isn't possible
to download it without projection?

```
var geom = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[100.06705522119341, 35.64726167759787],
[100.06705522119341, 26.242933904292144],
[115.62369584619341, 27.028556729687192],
[114.83268022119341, 36.28746466243914]]]),
    modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13Q1")
.filterBounds(geom)
.map(function(image){return image.clip(geom)}) 
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(4,6,'month'));
var modisNDVI = modis.select("NDVI");

var scaleNDVI = function(img){
  return img.multiply(0.0001)
}
modisNDVI = modisNDVI.map(scaleNDVI);

var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch') 
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(modisNDVI, "Folder", {scale:250});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(modisNDVI, 'modisNDVI', {
  scale: 250,
  region: geom.getInfo()
})
```

At [Exporting entire ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine using geetools for JavaScript or Python for Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300782) and [here](https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/wiki) Rodrigo explains how his gee tools work.