# Exporting several images from same collection in one task using Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to export several images (around 60) using Google Earth Engine. They are from the same collection and for the same geometry, but have different dates. I already have a list of the dates I need, but no matter what I do, I cannot seem to export them in one task.

Answer (score 1):

Earth Engine does not support exporting multiple images in one task. The developers are aware that this is a desirable feature, but it is not available at this time.

Third party tools to help set up separate export tasks for each image in a collection do exist ([example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276500/google-earth-engine-export-an-entire-collection?rq=1)) but I have not evaluated them and cannot recommend any.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information.