# Download MODIS burned area from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, modis

I'm trying to download the MODIS burned area data from GEE, however when I do I get

```
Error: Image.setDefaultProjection, argument 'image': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection.
```

How can I download all burned areas between the specified dates as a GEOTIFF?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD64A1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2015-01-01', '2016-01-01'));
var burnedArea = dataset.select('BurnDate');
var burnedAreaVis = {
  min: 30.0,
  max: 341.0,
  palette: ['4e0400', '951003', 'c61503', 'ff1901'],
};
Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 2);
Map.addLayer(burnedArea, burnedAreaVis, 'Burned Area');

Export.image.toDrive({
image: burnedArea,
description: '2015',
scale: 500,
region: geometry,
crs: 'EPSG:4236' 
});
```

For `region: geometry,` I am using a polygon I have drawn on the map.

I have tried `image: dataset` too.

Comment: You cannot export Image Collections, only single Images. See this question for a possible solution: [Google Earth Engine: Export an entire collection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276500/google-earth-engine-export-an-entire-collection)