# Batch download each monthly band from ImageCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to batch download all the monthly images (Blue band, SR_B2) of Landsat 8 but I am getting the following error:

```
ImageCollection (Error)
Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements.

In users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch
collection.size is not a function
```

I am trying to use @Rodrigo E. Principe's `batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive()` function for this purpose.

My last attempt was:

```
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

Map.centerObject(table);

//Create mask function
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 2, 3 and 5 are water, cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var waterBitMask = (1 << 2);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
.map(maskL8sr);

var landsat = landsat.select('SR_B2')
print (landsat)

var mean1 = landsat.select('SR_B2').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);

var B2 = mean1.select('SR_B2_mean')

// export collection to google drive
batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(
  B2, 
 'Folder', 
  {crs: 'EPSG: 3309',
  type: 'float',
  scale: 130,
  region: table});
```

My end goal is to have the entire monthly ImageCollection named as B2_YYYY_MM, where YYYY = year and MM = month. How can I do this?

I have a folder on my GDrive called Folder.

Comment: There is a batch downloader function made by Rodrigo E. Principe. Are you looking for [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276604/181131)?

Comment: I am aware of this function but I'm not sure that this the one I am looking for. Or at least I don't know how to modify it so I can download monthly images and spectral indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the function made by Rodrigo Principe, I created a `for` loop to export monthly images for several years. The only problem is that I can't download every month for the entire `ImageCollection`, so I have to download it (the collection) in chunks. The code is:

```
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
Map.centerObject(table);

//Create mask function
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 2, 3 and 5 are water, cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  var waterBitMask = (1 << 2);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

for (var y = 2019; y < 2020; y++) {
for (var i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
var landsat = landsat.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(i, i, 'month'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                      .filterBounds(table)
.map(maskL8sr);
var landsat = landsat.select('SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7', 'ST_B10')
print (landsat)

var mean2 = landsat.select('ST_B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table);

//Create variable for each band
var B2 = landsat.select('SR_B2').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B3 = landsat.select('SR_B3').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B4 = landsat.select('SR_B4').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B5 = landsat.select('SR_B5').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B6 = landsat.select('SR_B6').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B7 = landsat.select('SR_B7').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);
var B10 = landsat.select('ST_B10').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0).clip(table);

var B10 = B10.subtract(273.15)

var ndvi = B5.subtract(B4).divide(B5.add(B4)).rename('ndvi');

var ndbi = B6.subtract(B5).divide(B6.add(B5)).rename('ndbi');

var mean1 = landsat.select('SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7').reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2).clip(table);

var ebbi = mean1.expression('(SWIR - NIR)/ 10 * sqrt(SWIR + TIRS)',
{
'SWIR':B6,
'NIR':B5,
'TIRS': B10
}).rename('ebbi');

var nbi = mean1.expression('(RED - SWIR1) / (NIR)',
{
  'RED':B4,
  'NIR':B5,
  'SWIR1':B6,
}).rename('nbi');

var gndvi = mean1.expression('(NIR - GREEN) / (NIR + GREEN)',
{
  'NIR':B5,
  'GREEN':B3,
}).rename('gndvi');

var nbai = mean1.expression('((SWIR2 - SWIR1) / GREEN) / ((SWIR2 + SWIR1) / GREEN)',
{
  'SWIR2':B7,
  'SWIR1':B6,
  'GREEN':B2
}).rename('nbai');

var mbai = mean1.expression('(NIR + (1.57 * GREEN) + (2.4 * SWIR1)) / (1 + NIR)',
{
  'NIR':B5,
  'SWIR1':B6,
  'GREEN':B3
}).rename('mbai');

var evi = mean1.expression('2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))',
{
  'NIR':B5,
  'RED':B4,
  'BLUE':B2
}).rename('evi');

var bandSpectralList = [B4, B5, B10, evi, ndvi, gndvi, ndbi, ebbi, nbi, nbai, nbi];

var desc = "";

for (var banda = 0; banda < bandSpectralList.length; banda++) {
  
  switch (bandSpectralList[banda]) {
        case B2:
            desc = "blue";
          
            break;
        case B3:
            desc = "green";
           
            break;
        case B4:
            desc = "red";
            
            break;
        case B5:
            desc = "nir";
            
            break;
         case B6:
            desc = "swir1";
            break;
         case B7:
            desc = "swir2";
            break;
         case B10:
            desc = "tirs";
            break;
        case B10:
            desc = "tirs";
            break;
        case B10:
            desc = "tirs";
            break;
        case evi:
            desc = "evi";
            break;
        case ndvi:
            desc = "ndvi";
            break;
            
        case gndvi:
            desc = "gndvi";
            break;
            
        case ndbi:
            desc = "ndbi";
            break;
            
        case ebbi:
            desc = "ebbi";
            break;
        case nbi:
            desc = "nbi";
            break;
         case nbai:
            desc = "nbai";
            break;
        case mbai:
          desc = "mbai";
          break;
        // Add more cases as needed
        default:
            desc = "wrong_name";
            break;
    }
    
var currentBand = bandSpectralList[banda];

Export.image.toDrive({
image: currentBand,
description: desc.toString() + "_" + y + "_" +  ee.Number(i).format('%02d').getInfo(),
scale: 130, //100 for Band10
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table, 
folder: 'Landsat-8',
crs: 'EPSG:3309'
})
}
}
}
```