# How to export MODIS image from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm working on exporting MCD12C1 image from Google Earth Engine. However, when I run the code, it reminds me this message:

> Error: Image.setDefaultProjection, argument 'image': Invalid type. Expected type: Image. Actual type: ImageCollection. (Error code: 3).

I cannot find where the problem is.

[image]

Here's my code for exporting the image :

```
var startdate = '2018-01-01';
var enddate = '2020-12-31';

var MCD12C1data = MCD12C1.filterDate(startdate,enddate)
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .map(selectVetypes)
                  .map(Clip_ROI)
                  // .map(maskconfidence);
print(MCD12C1data)

Map.addLayer(MCD12C1data,{min:0,max:16},'MCD')
Map.addLayer(roi.style({color:'black',fillColor:'00000000'}),{},'roi')

function Clip_ROI(image){
  return image.clip(roi)
}

function maskconfidence(image){
  var percent = image.select('Majority_Land_Cover_Type_1')
  var mask = percent.gt(50) // Percent cover of each IGBP class at each pixel
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

function selectVetypes(image) {
  var types = image.select('Majority_Land_Cover_Type_1').rename('vegetationtypes')  
  return types.copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
}

Export.image.toDrive({
    image: MCD12C1data.select('vegetationtypes'),
    description: 'MCD12C1_masked',
    folder: "data",
    region: roi,
    scale: 5600,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you are trying to export an `ee.ImageCollection` while `Export.image.toDrive` supports only `ee.Image` type.

You have two options:

1. convert the image collection to image computing a stat like mean or median
2. export the image collection

If you want to export the image collection, this site has tackled this topic before:

- [Exporting each image from collection in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248216/exporting-each-image-from-collection-in-google-earth-engine) (JS version)
- [Google Earth Engine: Export an entire collection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276500/google-earth-engine-export-an-entire-collection) (Python version)

So, for your case, just load the awesome batch exporter from [Rodrigo Principe](https://github.com/gee-community/gee_tools):

```
var MCD12C1 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MCD12C1");
var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch')

var startdate = '2018-01-01';
var enddate = '2020-12-31';

var MCD12C1data = MCD12C1.filterDate(startdate,enddate)
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .map(selectVetypes)
                  .map(Clip_ROI)
                  // .map(maskconfidence);
print(MCD12C1data)

Map.addLayer(MCD12C1data,{min:0,max:16},'MCD')

function Clip_ROI(image){
  return image.clip(roi)
}

function maskconfidence(image){
  var percent = image.select('Majority_Land_Cover_Type_1')
  var mask = percent.gt(50) // Percent cover of each IGBP class at each pixel
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

function selectVetypes(image) {
  var types = image.select('Majority_Land_Cover_Type_1').rename('vegetationtypes')  
  return types.copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
}

batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(MCD12C1data.select('vegetationtypes'),
                'MCD12C1_masked', 
                {scale: 5600, 
                 crs: 'EPSG:4326',
                 region: roi})
```